# is there any way to skip rows in pandas until csv says "Flight Table"?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
N11682,aircraft,C172,,Cessna,C172SP,airplane,airplane_single_engine_land,fixed_tricycle,Piston,false,false,false,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Flights Table,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Date,AircraftID,From,To,Route,TimeOut,TimeOff,TimeOn,TimeIn,OnDuty,OffDuty,TotalTime,PIC,SIC,Night,Solo,CrossCountry,Distance,DayTakeoffs,DayLandingsFullStop,NightTakeoffs,NightLandingsFullStop,AllLandings,ActualInstrument,SimulatedInstrument,HobbsStart,HobbsEnd,TachStart,TachEnd,Holds,Approach1,Approach2,Approach3,Approach4,Approach5,Approach6,DualGiven,DualReceived,SimulatedFlight,GroundTraining,InstructorName,InstructorComments,Person1,Person2,Person3,Person4,Person5,Person6,FlightReview,Checkride,IPC,PilotComments
2020-11-01,N172TG,KSFM,KSFM,,,,,,,,0.8,0.8,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0,,,,,,,0.8,0.0,0.0,0.0,,,,,,,,,false,false,false
2020-11-01,N916BA,KSFM,KSFM,,,,,,,,0.5,0.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0,,,,,,,0.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,,,,,,,,,false,false,false31,N172TG,KSFM,KSFM,KASH,,,,,,,1.7,1.7,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.7,0.00,0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0,,,,,,,1.7,0.0,0.0,0.0,,,,,,,,,false,false,false
```

Heres my CSV, although I want it to skip multiple rows prior to the string "Flight Table" is this possible? Ive used skiprows but I need a little more versatility

Comment: what's the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Open the CSV file
2. loop through it as an iterator
3. if a line starts with your magic string, pass the remaining lines to `pandas.read_csv`

```
with open(mycsv, 'r') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        if line.startswith('Flights Table'):
            df = pandas.read_csv(fobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
count lines manually and use skiprows.

If lines keep changing - use readline till you find your string and count lines programmatically and feed to skiprows

skiprows : list-like, int or callable, optional
Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.